# Different textwidths on first and following pages with scrlttr2

Tags: margins, scrlttr2

Is it possible to have diverging values for `\textwidth` on the first page and all other pages.

On the first page I would like to set the width of the text to 12cm, on the following pages to 16cm.

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}

\setlength{\textwidth}{12cm}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Just me}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Just some place}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Some one \\ Some Place}
\opening{fsdfsdafs}

\blindtext[5]

\closing{Best wishes}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why do you want to change `\textwidth` (which is hard to coordinate with the output routine) rather than just change the width of the text (which is trivial, eg using an environment based on `quote` using a different, possibly negat?ive, indent)

Comment: I thought that adjusting `\textwidth` would be the right way.

Comment: Also when changing the width it is much much easier to have a forced page break, as changing the width mid-paragraph requires multiple passes and calculating a `\parshape`. Is a forced page break acceptable?

Comment: No, not really. The text should flow normally, without the need to enforce a pagebreak.

Comment: Ah in that case changing `\textwidth` is the least of your worries. It's not really possible in TeX in general but so long as there is only normal text and no large inserts, so you can guess accurately how many lines are on the page it is possible in simple cases.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle how is it that the answer is not really possible in TeX? How about if the text is not normal, or to complicate things even more, there are large inserts? So it won't work? Unbelievable.

Comment: @doed TeX typesetting is a two stage process: paragraphs are broken into lines onto a potentially infinite galley and then asynchronously the output routine is invoked which chops the galley into pages, adding floating inserts and page head and foot. This means that page breaking never affects linebreaking.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If you are referring to TeX, I never said otherwise. But this simple problem was aimed at breaking the page, although texnically the op never wanted such a thing, regardless of line breaking. I personally like the part when you said ''broken onto an infinite galley and then chops the galley into pages''. But you clearly said earlier that ''It's not really possible in general... and it is possible in simple cases''. So if the problem is adding inserts, as long as the values are figured out, and not by ''guess accurately'' which is just an oxymoron... it can be done,it's possible

Comment: @doed inserts are not really the problem (although they complicate the issue a bit) the hard case is just a long paragraph of text, as you have to calculate the parshape with a given number of short lines before the page break. I'm not sure what point you are trying to make as neither your comments nor answer address the problem of changing the line width mid-paragraph, which is the issue in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic technique is like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{babel,blindtext}

\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Just me}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Just some place}

\def\pshape#1{%
\parshape #1 \pshapexiicm{#1} 0pt 16cm }

\def\pshapexiicm#1{%
 \ifnum#1>1 0pt 12cm \expandafter
  \pshapexiicm\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\expandafter\relax\expandafter}\fi}

\begin{document}



\begin{letter}{Some one \\ Some Place}
\opening{fsdfsdafs}

\pshape{26}
aaa\blindtext[5]

\closing{Best wishes}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

To make it more general you need to trap paragraph breaks and restart the new paragraph with a `\parshape` that has a reduced number of short lines, depending on how many lines you just did. (code could be stolen from the `wrapfig` package for that:-)

If however you have stretch `parskip` or anything else complicated on the page working out exactly how many short lines you need can be challenging.

Comment: Is it more easier to use `afterpage`?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel It's easy to use afterpage, it just doesn't help.