# Execute a command at the start of every page

Tags: output-routine

Is there any way I can execute a command (`\ifthenelse` actually) at the start of every page?

I tried `\AtBeginShipout` (atbegshi) but that seem to get executed when the page is about to be rendered (shipped out). I want something different, as soon as the page is about to start.

Comment: What's the ultimate effect you're trying to achieve here? There are various mechanisms depending on what you have in mind: eg, something like adding a "DRAFT" watermark, or something like adding a header/footer, or something like putting "Theorem 2 (contd.)" if a previous section is overflowing onto this page.

Comment: @LevBishop Actually, I want to test if the page number has a certain value, if the answer is yes, I want to execute a predefined command at that point. And this command is not included the cases (adding .... onto this page) you enumerated.

Comment: What kind of command would you execute? Note that you cannot act on what TeX has already typeset; when it breaks a page, it usually has already typeset a complete paragraph, so this cannot be modified any more.

Comment: @egreg I am trying to find a solution to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145182/geometry-on-last-page-of-document). I find that I can find the last page number using the `lastpage` package. Now, if I can execute this at the start of every page, `\ifthenelse{\thepage=\pageref{LastPage}}{change geometry}{\relax}`, I can solve the problem. Definitely, the document will have to be compiled a number of times to _stablize_ everything.

Comment: @MMA You can't change the geometry mid page. And TeX is typicall mid page when it decides to make a page break.

Comment: @egreg So, perhaps, time to give up.

Comment: @MMA you'd need something like this but determining at what line the page breaks is hard in general http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142039/1090

Comment: @egreg limited forms of geometry change should be possible (eg, changing the top/bottom margins, or shifting the textblock left/right), just not ones that change the width of the textblock, since that has already been frozen.

Comment: @LevBishop If you're able to do it, you're welcome! `;-)`

Comment: @MMA for this kind of typographic nicety I think it's ok to do it manually with a manual pagebreak and geometry change command.

Comment: @egreg "should be possible" `\neq` "I can do it" :-)

Comment: @LevBishop I can not agree more. Situations like this arise when we want to add some back cover, or a colophon or something similar. It is very likely that I know what and where it is going to happen. Moreover, there is _only one_ last page in a document. My initial impression was to advise the OP of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145182/geometry-on-last-page-of-document), to handle the situation manually. Then I thought that I am not at liberty to control the end user and should not advise on what he should do. Also, I felt like taking a challenge (and failed). ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need the package [`bophook`](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bophook/bophook.pdf) to add commands at the beginning of each page:

> Using the `\AtBeginPage` hook, you can add material in the background of
>   a page. Think of it as a construct that does: For every page, create a
>   picture environment with its origin at the top left corner of the
>   paper (resp., output device). So for example, you can put an image
>   that is three centimeters from the left border and five from the top
>   border by saying
>
> ```
> \AtBeginPage{%
>    \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
>    \put(3, -5){\makebox(0,0)[tl]{\includegraphics{image}}}
> }
> ```